# Error dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube

Just trying to install Sonarqube without docker image, locally:

> -- dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.200\NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/tPointAgileOrg/tPoint/_packaging/tPoint/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\Users\Anri_Kezeroti\AppData\Local\Temp\utymnwsa.3vd\restore.csproj]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.200\NuGet.targets(130,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\Users\Anri_Kezeroti\AppData\Local\Temp\utymnwsa.3vd\restore.csproj]

> The tool package could not be restored.
> Tool 'dotnet-sonarscanner' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

> - You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
> - A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
> - The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
> - You mistyped the name of the tool.

> For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Proposed solution doesn't work for me. version 5.7.1

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue using v.5.7.2. There's a still open [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9555) about that topic. It seems when calling `dotnet install` it will implcitely also call `dotnet restore`, which will use your `Nuget.config`. When there's a private feed that needs authentication within that file, `dotnet install` will fail instead of just using the next feed available. So we can add the official nuget-feed and ignore any others using the following:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --add-source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json' --ignore-failed-sources
```

This will still issue a warning because the private feed cannot be accessed. However it will process further and you can use the tool.

Comment: I was with this problem to install wix package.
And this answer helped me.
dotnet tool install wix -g --add-source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json' --ignore-failed-sources

Answer (score 2):

dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 5.5.3

Specifying version solved problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is about authentication. Your nuget session may be expired or there might a problem about your credentials. In my case updating token in NuGet.Config solved this problem.

```
<add key="Username" value="your-username"/>
<add key="ClearTextPassword" value="your-new-token"/>
```